# How to avoid `npm-debug.log` creation

Tags: logging, npm

I run my testing script with `npm run test` and added `{script: {test: "jasmine"}}` to the `package.json`. My problem that every time I run the test, npm generates an `npm-debug.log` file, which I don't need. Is there a way to turn off this feature?

note:

I will use `npm run` only by running the tests on http://travis-ci.org/ if it is not possible to turn off this feature, will it generate a log file on the travis server by testing the build, or what?

**news 2016:**

There are news in the topic. At least after 5 years npm debug log was moved to the cache folder: https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/1548 , so it no longer pollutes our project folders.

Comment: Slight update to my answer. You can KIND OF do what you want. But probably not. (see answer).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Sort of good news, eveyone! You can suppress them by setting a command line parameter `-loglevel silent`, like `npm install sfdfsdf -loglevel silent`. However, this will also turn off feedback in the console, so I wouldn't do that.

I recommend ignoring them in your `.gitignore` file, so that they aren't officially in your project. Then, I just pretend they aren't there bothering my obsessive mind. =D

[npm config docs.](https://docs.npmjs.com/misc/config#loglevel)
[GitHub discussion about this issue.](https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/1548)

Answer (score 5):

In addition to m59's answer, you could modify your `npm run test` to include `&& rm npm-debug.log`. This will automatically delete the log after the test is finished, basically never letting you see it.

Comment: Actually, it's probably better to use `;` instead of `&&` since with the latter, the second command is only executed if the first one succceeds, but tests tend to fail :)